# Yii privatekey of Logged in User

Tags: php, mysql, yii

my application has 2 Tables in 1 DB. One is called USER ( id, uname, pw ,role) the other is USERZ (id, files, USER_id, name) for the Files.
There is a HAS_MANY and BELONGS_To relation with both Tables.

I can see Display Users and all Files. But what i whant to do is to see just the Files for each User ( So User with id = 1 cannot see Files from the User with id = 2)

My Controller looks like this:

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller
{
  ...
    public function actionVerwal()
    {   
        $model=new USER;
        $model2=new USERZ;
        $this->render('verwal',array('model'=>$model,'model2'=>$model2));
    }
 ...
}
```

My View verwal.php:

```
<?php
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($model2);
?>

<h1>List of Your Files<i></h1>

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model2->a($model2->id)
    , 'columns'=>array(
        'id', 'zname', 'USER_id'
    )
));
  ...
?>
```

My Model USERZ has the funktion a wich looks like this:

```
public function a($id)
    {   $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('USER_id', $id);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

So what i get is a list with all the files. I dont know how to change the compare the USER_id just with the ID from the logged in USER so i can get the rigt files and not all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, `$criteria->compare('USER_id', $id, true);` why do You use third parameter here? Remove it or set as false.
Its

> $partialMatch whether the value should consider partial text
>   match (using LIKE and NOT LIKE operators). Defaults to false, meaning
>   exact comparison.

To get logged user id in Yii you can use `Yii::app()->user->getId();`

Comment: I deleted it, it was a leftbehind from a other thing i whanted to test. But that does not change anything. Thanks for the explaining

Comment: ok i changed  -- 'dataProvider'=>$model2->a($model2->id)  -- to      'dataProvider'=>$model2->a(Yii::app()->user->getId()) but now no id is matching ... and i think its because if i  echo Yii::app()->user->getId() i get the uname instad of the id

Comment: Hmm it shouldn't be so... Check UserIdentity class and search what do you save to id ($this->_id) property.

Comment: do you mean in my authenticate() method ? -- because there are just 2 funktions in my UserIdentity.php. First is called authenticate() and second getId().